# Improved anagram generator

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function in Python that will generate anagrams of a given word.  I'm not just looking for code that will rearrange the letters aimlessly.  All the options given must be real words.   I currently have a solution, which to be honest I took most of this code from a YouTube video, but it is very slow for my purpose and can only provide one word responses to a single word given.  It uses a 400,000 word dictionary to compare the words it is going though, called "dict.txt".

My goal is to get this code to mimic how well this website's code works:
https://wordsmith.org/anagram/

I could not find the javascript code when reviewing the network activity using Google Chrome's developer tool, so I believe the code is probably in the background, and is possibly using Node.js.  This would perhaps make it faster than Python, but given how much faster it is I believe there is more to it than just the programming language.  I assume they are using some type of search algorithm rather than just going through each line one by one like I am.   I also like the fact that their response is not limited to a single word, but can break up the word given to provide more options to the user.  For example, an anagram of "anagram" is "nag a ram".

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
def init_words(filename):
    words = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            word = line.strip()
            words[word] = 1
    return words

def init_anagram_dict(words):
    anagram_dict = {}
    for word in words:
        sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(list(word)))
        if sorted_word not in anagram_dict:
            anagram_dict[sorted_word] = []
        anagram_dict[sorted_word].append(word)
    return anagram_dict


def find_anagrams(word, anagram_dict):
    key = ''.join(sorted(list(word)))
    if key in anagram_dict:
        return set(anagram_dict[key]).difference(set([word]))
    return set([])


#This is the first function called.  
def make_anagram(user_word):
    x = str(user_word)
    lower_user_word = str.lower(x)
    word_dict = init_words('dict.txt')
    result = find_anagrams(lower_user_word, init_anagram_dict(word_dict.keys()))
    list_result = list(result)
    count = len(list_result)
    if count > 0:
        random_num = random.randint(0,count -1)
        anagram_value = list_result[random_num]
        return ('An anagram of %s is %s.  Would you like me to search for another word?' %(lower_user_word, anagram_value))
    else:
        return ("Sorry, I could not find an anagram for %s." %(lower_user_word))
```

Comment: Don't load and initialise the dictionary every time you look for an anagram. You can do that once, when the program starts. Or you can do it just once (ever), "pickle" it and store it on disk.

Comment: @molbdnilo, thank you for the suggestion.  That definitely makes sense.

Comment: Finding an anagram for a single word is straightforward (build a table of words keyed by a value that represents a histogram of letter counts, and then do lookups into it). Finding multi-word anagrams is much more complex -- more or less equivalent to the bin-packing problem, I think? If so, I think it's probably NP-hard, but I'm not certain of that.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielPryden.  I did not know about that problem and I will certainly look into it.

Comment: If you can decide on an upper bound of how many words you support in advance, you can build your table using each word multiple times. You just need O(n^m) space and time (where n is the number of words in your dictionary and m is the number of words in a single anagram you support) to build the table; then lookups are still effectively O(1) (or, more precisely, O(k) where k is the number of matching results). However, O(n^m) gets *extremely* large as m increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dictionary of anagrams by grouping words by their sorted text.  All words that have the same sorted text are anagrams of each other:

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open("/usr/share/dict/words","r") as wordFile:
    words = wordFile.read().split("\n")

anagrams = defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    anagrams["".join(sorted(word))].append(word)

aWord  = "spear"
result = anagrams["".join(sorted(aWord))]

print(aWord,result) 
# ['asper', 'parse', 'prase', 'spaer', 'spare', 'spear']
```

*Using 235,000 words, the response time is instantaneous*

In order to obtain multiple words forming an anagram of the specified word, you will need to get into combinatorics.  A recursive function is probably the easiest way to go about it:

```
from itertools   import combinations,product
from collections import Counter,defaultdict

with open("/usr/share/dict/words","r") as wordFile:
    words = wordFile.read().split("\n")

anagrams = defaultdict(set)
for word in words:
    anagrams["".join(sorted(word))].add(word)
counters = { w:Counter(w) for w in anagrams }
minLen   = 2 # minimum word length

def multigram(word,memo=dict()):
    sWord = "".join(sorted(word))
    if sWord in memo: return memo[sWord]
    result     = anagrams[sWord]
    wordCounts = counters.get(sWord,Counter())
    for size in range(minLen,len(word)-minLen+1):
        seen = set()
        for combo in combinations(word,size):
            left  = "".join(sorted(combo))
            if left in seen or seen.add(left): continue
            left = multigram(left,memo)
            if not left: continue
            right = multigram("".join((wordCounts-Counter(combo)).elements()),memo)
            if not right: continue
            result.update(a+" "+b for a,b in product(left,right) )
    memo[sWord] = list(result)
    return memo[sWord]
```

*Performance is good up to 12 character words.  Beyond that the exponential nature of combinations start to take a heavy toll*

```
result = multigram("spear")
print(result)
# ['parse', 'asper', 'spear', 'er spa', 're spa', 'se rap', 'er sap', 'sa per', 're asp', 'ar pes', 'se par', 'pa ers', 're sap', 'er asp', 'as per', 'spare', 'spaer', 'as rep', 'sa rep', 'ra pes', 'pa ser', 'es rap', 'es par', 'prase']

len(multigram("mulberries"))     # 15986      0.1 second   10 letters
len(multigram("raspberries"))    # 60613      0.2 second   11 letters
len(multigram("strawberries"))   # 374717     1.3 seconds  12 letters
len(multigram("tranquillizer"))  # 711491     7.6 seconds  13 letters
len(multigram("communications")) # 10907666  52.2 seconds  14 letters
```

In order to avoid any delay, you can convert the function to an iterator.  This will allows you to get the first few anagrams without having to generate them all:

```
def iMultigram(word,prefix=""):
    sWord = "".join(sorted(word))
    seen = set()
    for anagram in anagrams.get(sWord,[]):
        full = prefix+anagram
        if full in seen or seen.add(full): continue
        yield full        
    wordCounts = counters.get(sWord,Counter(word))
    for size in reversed(range(minLen,len(word)-minLen+1)): # longest first           
        for combo in combinations(sWord,size):
            left  = "".join(sorted(combo))
            if left in seen or seen.add(left): continue
            for left in iMultigram(left,prefix):
                right = "".join((wordCounts-Counter(combo)).elements())
                for full in iMultigram(right,left+" "):
                    if full in seen or seen.add(full): continue
                    yield full

from itertools import islice
list(islice(iMultigram("communications"),5)) # 0.0 second

# ['communications', 'cinnamomic so ut', 'cinnamomic so tu', 'cinnamomic os ut', 'cinnamomic os tu']
```

Comment: Thank you, Alain.  That code is definitely a lot cleaner than the one I was using.  Unfortunately, it is also limited to single word results.

Comment: I got it now.  Edited my answer to add multi-word anagrams.

Comment: Thank you, Alain.  I just tested it and it works great!